# When can we say that a linear transformation is equivalent to a change of basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I'm aware that every change of basis is a linear transformation, but the converse isn't true. What conditions must a linear transformation $T$ satisfy for us to call it a change of basis? One condition that I can think of is that $T$ should be invertible, but I'm not sure that's enough to  call it a change of basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invertibility is equivalent to the span's dimension staying the same, which in turn is equivalent to the linear transformation giving a basis.

Let the original basis $B$ have $n$-dimensional span. (This is just the vector space's dimension. If the elements of $B$ are linearly independent so that $B$ has a minimal number of elements, $B$ has $n$ elements.) The dimension of $\operatorname{span}\{Tb|b\in B\}$ is then the rank of $T$, which is $n$ iff $T$ is invertible.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to bother, but could you include some more details if convenient? I can't properly follow your answer since I've recently started with the subject.

Comment: @ShirishKulhari I'll edit the answer in a few minutes. In the mean time, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) link helps.

Comment: Thank you, I'll start going through that link right away.

Answer (score 0):

Any invertible matrix can be interpreted as a change of basis between the standard basis and the basis consisting of its columns.  To effect the change of basis, conjugate by the matrix.

So, if $P$ is said matrix, $P^{-1}AP$ will be the matrix $A$  in the new basis.

Since $P$ transforms from the basis consisting of its columns to the standard basis, vectors are described as  *contravariant*.

Whereas the conjugation described above on matrices is *$1$-co*-, *$1$-contra-variant*.